# Strange coordinate after use tippecanoe and Mapbox/pbf

Tags: mapbox, vector-tiles, pbf, tippecanoe

I am trying to make vector tile base on Mapbox pbf standard.

First, convert data from `EPSG4326` to `EPSG3857` and export as .json.
By using QGIS to export data and set CRS as `EPSG3857`.

Second, use mapbox/tippecanoe to generate vector tile in pbf format.

Third, use mapbox/pbf, @mapbox/vector-tile and zlib, and use toGeoJSON.

Finally, I got the following results:

```js
geojson {
    type: 'Feature',
    geometry: {
        type: 'LineString',
        coordinates: [[Array], [Array], [Array], [Array], [Array] ]
    },
    properties: {
        FNODE_: 27,
        TNODE_: 27,
        LPOLY_: 9,
        RPOLY_: 1,
        LENGTH: 1.567,
        HYD1_4M_: 278,
        HYD1_4M_ID: 1454,
        GBCODE: 23010,
        NAME: '濂庡悲娌',
        LEVEL_RIVE: 5,
        LEVEL_LAKE: 1
    }
}
```

and in the coordinates:

```
[ -48.427734375, 74.74118495548183 ]    
[ -48.7353515625, 74.78737860165961 ]    
[ -48.6474609375, 74.74118495548183 ]    
[ -48.4716796875, 74.71803680830911 ]    
[ -48.427734375, 74.74118495548183 ]
```

This coordinate is very strange, the origin data is in `EPSG4326` and I convert the data in `EPSG3857`, but the above data is obviously not `EPSG4326` or `EPSG3857`. I know the exact location of my data, so this data will not show negative latitude and longitude under `EPSG4326`.

Does anyone know why this is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The GeoJSON data that you feed into Tippecanoe should be in EPSG:4326. There is no need to project it.